# If you have a tableau proof for $\Box A$, show that there is also a tableau proof for A.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, modal-logic, kripke-models

If you have a tableau proof for $\Box A$, Show that there is also a tableau proof for A.

Here is my attempt but I'm not sure if it's correct:

If we have a tableau proof for $\Box A$, it means that all possible worlds that are accessible from the current world satisfy $A$. Therefore, if we can show that there is at least one world that satisfies $A$ in the current world, then $A$ must be true.

To show this, we can take the original tableau proof for $\Box A$ and add an additional branch where we assume $\neg A$. Then, we can apply the $\Box$ rule to this branch, which will generate a contradiction, since we know that all accessible worlds satisfy $A$. This contradiction allows us to close the branch and conclude that $A$ must be true in the current world.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state which modal logic you are working in. I will assume that you are working in System K, which places no restrictions on the accessibility relation. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) and [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) for details.

---

First, let's check that the statement is actually true semantically.

We want to show that $\models \square A \implies \models A$.

Consider the frame with one world $w$ and an accessibility relation $R$  that is never true. Suppose $A$ is false at $w$.

$ (w, R), w \Vdash \square A$ is vacuously true.

However, $(w, R), w \Vdash A$ is **false**.

Whichever tableau method you are using, it must be sound and complete, so the theorem you want to show is false **provided we don't have assumptions on the accessibility relation that rule out this frame**.

---

Your rule, however, is the converse of the *necessitation rule* $\models A \implies \models \square A$, which is true even in system $K$.

You can prove $\vdash A \implies \vdash \square A$ by proving it semantically and then appealing to the soundness and completeness of the tableau calculus.

Proving $\vdash A \implies \vdash \square A$ without appealing to the semantics is harder, and doing it requires that you pick a specific tableau calculus and understand how it handles the bookkeeping details of possible worlds. I personally like the [world-labeled tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#World-labeled_tableau) with pseudoformulas denoting accessibility assumptions (like $1R2$ denoting that world $2$ is accessible from world $1$) being written off to the side.